# Creating dynamic workflows

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation

I am currently trying to make an application that allows the user to create workflows.

Store them and then consume them using a wizard style interface (back, next, fill inn textboxes, with road crosses).

I have been looking at many technologies, but i am struggling with finding a framework that allows me to do this.

I have looked at Microsoft workflow, but it seems that the workflows that are created are stored statically.

Is this correct? Do you have suggestions to what framework is the best? maybe some tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute workflows dynamically. What you can do is give some GUI to create workflows (.xaml files ) to the user and give him to choose and execute workflows. [Here is how to do it](http://www.developerfusion.com/media/84955/endpointtv-lab-introduction-to-wf4-exercise-4-dynamic-workflows-with-xaml/).